# Improving minimax algorithm for Tic Tac Toe

Tags: python, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

I have coded a minimax algorithm with alpha-beta pruning for a 4x4 Tic Tac Toe, in which the players who gets 3 marks in a row wins. However, it seems that the first to move wins in this game, such that minimax doesn't even try to make it harder for the player to win, because no other possible move can improve the outcome (since minimax assumes optimal play from both sides). Therefore, I added the condition that the algorithm will choose the best move that will also maximize the game length (while assuming that the other player will try to win with least moves), and I tried to do that by adding 2 more "alpha" and "beta" variables, but for the game length.

My game has worked fine without this new condition, but when I add it, it doesn't work properly, and the algorithm will not avoid losing, which minimax should have prevented. Below is the part of the code which solves for the optimal move.

Note that I used 1 and -1 to represent the players, that is, o = 1 and x = -1, and they are themselves the score of their win. A draw returns 0.

```
def optimalmove(board, player, alpha, beta,optlength,movementlength,worlength):

    stator = checkstate4(board) # Contains the state of the game. stator[0] is whether the game has reached the end or not,
    # stator[1] is who has won (or draw), stator[2] are the possible moves
    if len(stator[2]) == boardsize ** 2:
        # if it is the first move, pick the corner as it has already been calculated
        # to be the optimal, in order to reduce time
        return([0, [0, 0],movementlength])
    if stator[0]: #If at the end return which one has won
        return([stator[1], [],movementlength])
    movement = [] #best movement
    for move in stator[2]: #loops through each possible move
        localboard = deepcopy(board) #creates a copy of the board to not change the original
        localboard[move[0]][move[1]] = player
        quality = optimalmove(localboard, player * (-1), alpha, beta,optlength,movementlength+1,worlength)
        #since it made a move, increase the move list length by one
        if player == o: #'O' maximizes the score and wants to reduce the length of the game
            if (quality[0] > alpha) or ((quality[0] >= alpha) and (quality[2] < worlength)):
                # If it finds a better move, so be it. But if it finds a move as good as the previously best seen,
                # take the one that will reach the end the fastest
                alpha = quality[0]
                movement = move
                worlength = quality[2] #set the shortest game length seen to the current one
        elif player == x: #'X' minimizes the score and wants to increase the length of the game
            if (quality[0] < beta) or ((quality[0] <= beta) and (quality[2] > optlength)):
                # If it finds a better move, so be it. But if it finds a move as good as the previously best seen,
                # take the one that will reach the end the longest
                beta = quality[0]
                movement = move
                optlength = quality[2] #set the longest game length seen to the current one
        if alpha >= beta:
            # prunes
            break

    if player == o:
        return ([alpha, movement,worlength])
    else:
        return ([beta, movement,optlength])
```

Comment: It is a fact that of the first player takes the Centre, then they are guaranteed to win.  Instead of optimising for game Length, you could copy the common rule that the first player is not allowed to claim the Centre on first turn.

Comment: Here the utility of a move is different for each player meaning that the game is probably not "zero sum" anymore so I don't think min-max will work here.

Comment: @apokryfos, the idea is that minimax will do its job and just choose the move that maximizes the game length from the equally best moves in terms of the final outcome.

Comment: I'm confused. TTT is a draw no matter who moves first, not a win. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe): "It is a solved game, with a forced draw assuming best play from both players." Your MM should be unbeatable, i.e. able to win or draw in all games it plays from the beginning.